# not receiving array content of JSON.stringify() while sending a text with white space in array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am trying to send a array of strings using JSON.stringify to another page.
while receiving that array i am using json_decode. 
my problem is that when i insert a value in array without white space. its working well. but when i enter a text string with white space. it is not receiving on another page.
i also check while JSON.stringify is sending data or not . it sending well. but when i decode it and try to print value. it print nothing.

here is code
1. on page sending data 
JSON.stringify(array name);

2.On page recieving data
$arr=json_decode(html_entities_decode($_REQUEST['array name']),True);

3.while printing
echo$arr[0];

this working well with array element without white space but not with text with white space.
elements of array i am getting from an input box value.
Thanks in advance.

sorry for inconvience..
here is complete code

on page sending data.

```
var nmd=new Array();
 var nam;
for(var i=1;i<=newseats;i++)
{
nam=document.getElementById('inputbox').value;
nmd.push(nam);
 }
var dmon=JSON.stringify(nmd);
alert(dmon);
var frm="<form action='checkfrm.php' method=POST id='confrm'>";
frm+="<input name=namego type=hidden value="+dmon+">";
frm+="</form>";
document.getElementById("fr").innerHTML=frm;
document.getElementById("confrm").submit();
```

on page receiving data

```
$namer=json_decode(html_entity_decode($_REQUEST['namego']),True);
echo"<script>alert(";
echo$namer[0];
echo");</script>";
```

on first page it showing value in alert but on next page can't retrieve value

Comment: Please add 4 spaces in front of every code line

Comment: And if you already made pseudocode, use valid var names (array name isnt)

Comment: everything is working well when i enter a value in textbox without white space.  but not with white space.